# How to use on instance service in whole Angular app?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have the following service that emits events:

```
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class TabEvents {
  private routeParameters: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  listenRouteParameters(): Observable<any> {
    return this.routeParameters.asObservable();
  }

  emitRouteParmeters(parameters: any) {
    this.routeParameters.next(parameters);
  }
}
```

Why each time when I open component where I listen events:

```
this.tabEvents.listenRouteParameters().subscribe(parameters => {
   // get event
})
```

It is called twice? then thrice?

It seems that each time component created subscriber, but does not unsubscribe. Why if component is destroyed?

Does Observer work in separated thread?

Comment: Your subscription may last beyond the lifetime of the component unless you unsubscribe (calls complete). You may want to look at the pipeable operator `take(1)` which takes the first event then completes. All observers have next ( out of the triple next, error, complete function call backs) called whenever observable next is called hence multiple calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your component is destroyed you need to unsubscribe from the observable in some way. For example:

```
private _routeParamsSub : Subscription;

this._routeParamsSub = this.tabEvents.listenRouteParameters().subscribe(parameters => {
   // get event
})

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._routeParamsSub.unsubscribe()
}
```

Another approach you might try is using `takeUntil`

```
private _destroyed$: Subject<null> = new Subject();

this.tabEvents.listenRouteParameters()
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
    )
    .subscribe(parameters => {
        // get event
    })

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroyed$.next();
    this._destroyed$.complete();
}
```

The end result is the same but you may find the latter more useful if you have multiple subscriptions and don't won't to create a subscription variable for each, or an array to hold all subscriptions.

Comment: Could I discard observer if I call next observer in service instead component?

Comment: @user3573738 You put this code in each component that subscribes to `listenRouteParameters()`